# How do I create a filter on 'State' from 'zip' data

Tags: tableau-api

I have an excel file which has 8K zips from the US and it looks like below -

```
ZIP 
30338 
94066
```

I have loaded them into tableau to get the geographical map of those zips. How can I create a filter on `State` now?
[image]

Comment: Tableau maps zipcodes to lat,lon and any association with the state is simply a visual artifact, a side-effect of geocoordinate mapping.  So you can't do what you are asking, not without bringing in a zip-to-state data source.

Comment: Like Dmitry said, you need to include state either in your Excel file or look online for a zip-to-state file. There are dozens of them available on the internet. Some are more accurate and up to date than others.